# Executing Karma giving permission denied error

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, karma-runner

I installed karma locally using

`npm install karma --save-dev`

and then i tried

`$ ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start`

Then i get this error

```
vagrant@development:$ ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start
-bash: ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma: Permission denied
vagrant@development:$ ls -liah ./node_modules/karma/bin/
total 4.0K
54696 drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant www-data 102 Nov 17 19:24 .
54688 drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant www-data 544 Nov 17 15:57 ..
54697 -rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant www-data  50 Nov 15 02:43 karma
```

What can be the reason

http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/intro/installation.html

```
vagrant@development:$ sudo chmod +x ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma
vagrant@development:$ ls -liah ./node_modules/karma/bin/
total 4.0K
54696 drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant www-data 102 Nov 17 19:24 .
54688 drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant www-data 544 Nov 17 15:57 ..
54697 -rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant www-data  50 Nov 15 02:43 karma
```

Comment: I tried giving 'chmod +x' , did NOT work. How exactly it worked for u?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `./node_modules/karma/bin/karma` executable does not have execution privileges for your user. You can `chmod` it to give you the right privileges with:

```
$ chmod +x ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma
```

To avoid this in the future, simply install it with `npm install -g karma-cli` (*globally*).

Comment: @KKJOJ output of `ls -l`? This will set it to execution mode, and your previous `ls -l` says explicitly no `x`.

Comment: I have added the output in question. Look like mode of file is not changing even with sudo

Comment: @KKJOJ maybe try `chmod 777 ..`? If that doesn't work, I'm really not sure.

Comment: @KKJOJ try installing globally with `-g karma-cli`.